# High performance real time project .NET, SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, c#-4.0, real-time

I have a demanding project and I need your starting guidelines on this!

- I need to have a database with approximately 2.000.000 records with markers lat,lng. These markers are moving objects and update their positions every 10 seconds. If the received marker does not exist in the database it needs to be inserted.
- I need somehow the end user to have a realtime data in the web request e.g (www.example.com/getmarkers?minlat=x&maxlat=x&minlng=x&maxlng=x&zoom=x) for the specified zoom and eliminate the markers that overlap each other.
- The main server app will receive the update commands via TCP and UDP protocol on multiple ports

Can I use C sharp and a memory datatable to do all these updates every second? Also can the end user hit this datatable so everything stays in memory to be faster? What do you think about performance and what is your opinion for develop a project like this? Real time data is what I need

I prefer to user C#, SQL Server 2008

Thanks a lot

Comment: Will users be frequently requesting the same fields? Are these "markers" aggregated?

Comment: Some yes but not all. Is spread around the globe

Comment: What is the anticipated load? I.e. do you expect your api to be hit every minute, 100 times a minute?

Comment: This is going to be a website with google maps. Each time a user move the map a new call will be made to get the markers on the current view point. Also the refresh on the map it need to be done as fast as possible. 5 secs gonna be perfect. Also we expect over 800 users connected to this website so there gonna be a lot of requests. Is this possible to be done?

Comment: If you are doing 200,000 inserts/updates per second and need real-time reporting on the data, you are talking a very serious database system.  A distributed, in-memory database is likely to be the way to go.

Comment: You mean a datatable in .net? How this database can be accessable from the web and the main standalone app?

Comment: 200 000 updates per seconds is really quite a lot. I would stay away from any SQL database in this kind of case. Search the net for NoSQL: there are a lot of products in this category

Comment: Do you know if the .net datatable can handle all this requests? And somehow let the web users access the main app and make the requests to this in memory datatable?

Comment: When all of your marbles are in one box you've placed a dangerous wager. If your server goes down do you need to have a copy of the data somewhere else? How much can you tolerate losing, e.g. 10 seconds of updates? How quickly do you need to be online again? Replicating real-time data isn't trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I’d start of by making estimates based on following data with the goal of estimation number of requests per minute or second.

Average number of moving markers at any time. If you have 200 vehicles to track how many do you expect to be moving simultaneously? Does time of the day matter? If it does make sure you make calculations based on the peak hours.

How many simultaneous requests from users do you expect? If you have 800 users are they going to be using the application throughout the whole day or only several times a day or once a week?

Once you get the data multiply it by at least 3. This will accommodate for all false assumptions you may have made in the calculations and allow for future growth.

Once you get the final number it will be a lot easier to decide whether you need only one  two 6-core CPU server, four 12 core CPU server or a mini data center with in memory databases and other advanced stuff